# gradle force build tools version on third party libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

how can I force a library to use sdk build tools 19.1.0 or above without forking/manually editing the build.gradle file for the library?

I keep getting this error when using libraries...

```
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (.......) is too low for project ':somelibrary'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The lack easy way to do it is beyond my understanding. Tons of people use library projects that they don't own, have to build with Jenkins or have other reasons not to touch them and don't want to fork them for personal use.

Anyway, I found a solution [here](https://plus.googleapis.com/wm/4/+Gon%C3%A7aloSilva/posts/3EYhtGdknij).

Will copy it here just in case:

In you root build.gradle add

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 20
    buildToolsVersion = "20.0.0"
}
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will apply compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to any android modules you have.

And in your main project's build.gradle change dependencies to this:

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

Basically you are defining them once and could use from anywhere.

Cheers.

Comment: Because I was a little confused about which gradle files, in Android Studio it might look like root build.gradle (Project: [ProjectName]), main project's build.gradle (Module: app)

Comment: awsome，this is elegant and clean

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to update the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` values only when the `buildToolsVersion` value is too low, you can first compare the version number of the subproject and only update if needed. This way you make minimal changes to other projects and have less projects to check if things go wrong.

So, let's say that Android Studio is telling you that you need a minimum build tools version of `25.0.0`, then in your root `build.gradle`, here's how you would check each sub-project's `buildToolsVersion` and only change it if it's less than `25.0.0`:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && VersionNumber.parse(project.property("android").buildToolsVersion) < VersionNumber.parse("25.0.0")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 25
                buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This fixed these errors from 'react-native-sqlite-storage' "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'" and "'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'"  etc.  If someone googles these errors, the main reason was the difference between my  project's buildToolsVersion and 'react-native-sqlite-storage' library's buildToolsVersion. That library uses 23.0.1 and my project uses 26.0.1.  And finally with the answer above, i succesfully forced the library to use 26.0.1 version of the build tools and the errors gone.