# Multiple required build tools for packaging a react-native app to Android

Tags: android, react-native, travis-ci, node-modules

I am configuring travis auto packaging of a react native app, I am forced to specify 3 versions for build tools just because react-native-keychain and react-native-maps node libs need different versions. This cost me a long time downloading all versions.

```
  - build-tools-25.0.2
  - build-tools-23.0.1
  - build-tools-23.0.3
  - android-25
  - android-23
```

Is there a way to force react-native-keychain and react-native-maps to be installed with the same version of the main project?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494077/gradle-force-build-tools-version-on-third-party-libraries

Comment: @Ardock it resolved my problem, thanks