# Android Dependency error

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have following code in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

But i get error for the following line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

[image]

[image]

Can any one help me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: You are using a library (`com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7`) that relies upon three-year-old versions of the support libraries. I recommend that you either stop using that library or fork it, so that you can maintain your fork and keep it up to date with respect to the support library version.

Comment: yup.thanks CommonsWare.Because of that its giving an erorr

Answer (score 1):

> problem is with 
>   compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7' check below screen shot

[image: problem is with compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7']

Solution :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736483/793943

Answer (score 0):

This means your build version is 26.0.1 but ur support gradle version is 26.0.0. Change the support appcompat version from 26.0.0 to 26.0.1 and build.

Comment: @AAalap Patel.that i have tried still getting eror.even i have added alpha1

Comment: Build tools version must be latest, but other libraries version - not

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code to your project level build.gradle file, it should work

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
       }
    }
}
```