# What is the impact of using a forcing a common buildToolsVersion across submodules in Android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

Third party libraries like React Mative forces a specific buildToolsVersion (at the time of writing at "23.0.1") and other versions use some higher value. There seems to be a work around for this by forcing each submodule to use a particular version([gradle force build tools version on third party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494077/gradle-force-build-tools-version-on-third-party-libraries)).

The above would work for me since the infrastructure i am using cannot support the latest version so I have to resort to an older one. I am curious to know how this can impact the behavior of the app if any during run time. Also I plan to use an SDK version at 25 so the major versions won't align.

It would be best if there is no runtime impact and any errors happen during compilation time but I am not sure how exactly this works.

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious to know how this can impact the behavior of the app if any during run time

`buildToolsVersion` is the version of the compilers (aapt, dx, renderscript compiler) that you want to use without any impact with your runtime.
Also you can use a higher version of the build-tools than your `compileSdkVersion`.

More [details here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html).