# Flutter, android project runs into an error while compiling

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-plugin

Ran into build errors, migrated to android X,
Changed the plugins 
.....................................

Running "flutter packages get" in prototype...                   1.4s
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 5 Plus in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:706: error: cannot find symbol
  private void reportException(Result result, @Nullable Exception exception) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:610: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.SignInCompleteListener
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:629: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.TaskVoidCompleteListener
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:647: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.GetSignInMethodsCompleteListener
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:187: error: cannot find symbol
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                              ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:492: error: cannot find symbol
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\kenny\Documents\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.1+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:559: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                          ^
  symbol: class NonNull
9 errors
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See .... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208772/error-resource-androidattr-fontvariationsettings-not-found)

Comment: Might want to look into "Migrating to AndroiX".

Comment: have you move to android X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you migrated your project to AndroidX?**

Looks like you haven't migrated your project to AndroidX.

### What is AndroidX?

> "AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library. All new android projects are requested to be migrated to AndroidX if your project is dependant on libraries using AndroidX"

[read more here ...](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

### How to migrate to AndroidX

> **Summary**
>
> *[ Prerequisite: Android Studio 3.2+. ]*
>   *[ Please take a backup before proceeding.]*
>
> 1. Open your android project in Android Studio
> 2. Add these two lines to your **gradle.properties** file
>      *android.useAndroidX=true*
>
>      *android.enableJetifier=true*
> 3. Go to your app level **build.gradle** file and change your
>      **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to **28**
> 4. From menu click on **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**
> 5. Optionally you can take a zip backup on prompt.
> 6. Once the list is prepared, click on '**Do Refactor**'

[read more here ...](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Migrating didn't work, changed my initial post to the error message

Comment: @rizu Migrating has worked. This is a different error and you need to create a new question. Please don't edit your question. This will confuse other stackoverflow users who read this question in the future. So I request you to put back the old question in and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a similar problem, because a firebase plugin used `compileSdkVersion 27` - I simply forked it to use `28`, but it should also be possible to override it from the project root's `build.gradle`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50916298/109219

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the solution but it didn't work, I have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

have you move to android X? if yes,

1)make sure your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 28

2)sometimes kotlin version is also a cause of this type of error, make sure you use the       latest version of kotlin .(ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10', in my case).

3)classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

4) follow firebase instruction carefully, for adding your application to firebase.

5) if you are using firebase_auth, make sure you enter SHA-1 and SHA-256 signature while adding your application to firebase.

don't forget to consider flutter clean as last step

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

The Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries.